# How to receive sip response?

Tags: sip, tapi

How do I receive responses from sip using php/nodejs/javascript.
What I have:

- Software Telephone (SIP/TAPI) required!
- Remote Debian Server (can't login to provider)

I'd like to open browser and Software VOIP Telephone and run a procedure.

Procedure:

- Select Telephonnumber from Datebase (mysql)
- Call selected nummber
- receive response
- work with response

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use SIP over WebSockets: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ibc-sipcore-sip-websocket
This protocol is supported by OverSIP, Kamailio, Asterisk, OfficeSIP.

And here are some *usable* libraries implementing SIP client over WS:

- http://sipml5.org/
- http://jssip.net/